# change state with ui-router when button is clicked

Tags: angularjs

In my angular 1.4.X app, I change state in an `<a>` element via the `ui-sref` directive like so:

```
<a ui-sref="challenges.show({ challengeId: challenge.id })">Change state</a>
```

What is the equivalent syntax when using a button instead of a link

```
<button>Change state</button>
```

Comment: `<button ui-sref="challenges.show({ challengeId: challenge.id })" class="btn btn-danger navbar-btn">
      Schedule
 </button>`

Comment: @Makoto how it would work :0 check docs https://ui-router.github.io/docs/0.3.1/#/api/ui.router.state.directive:ui-sref

Answer (score 3):

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', ['ui.router']);

'use strict';

app.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', '$locationProvider', function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider) {

  $stateProvider
    .state("main", {
      url: "/main",
      resolve: {
        test: function() {
          alert("Triggered main state");
          return true;
        }
      }
    });

}]);


app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'World';
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
  <link data-require="bootstrap-css@3.1.1" data-semver="3.1.1" rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <script>
    document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');
  </script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.2.x" src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.13/angular.js" data-semver="1.2.13"></script>
  <script src="http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js" ></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">

  <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
    </div>  
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
      <li>
        <button class="btn btn-danger navbar-btn" ui-sref="main" >Button Submit</button>
      </li>
      
    </ul>
  </nav>


</body>

</html>
```

**ui-sref can be binded to any clickable element**

```
<button ui-sref="challenges.show({ challengeId: challenge.id })" class="btn btn-danger navbar-btn"> Schedule </button>
```

Comment: @Little, pls check this answer.

Comment: @PankajParkar, pls check the snippet above.

Comment: my bad, Thanks, looked at API now(still haven't got cleared), learnt something new today +1

Answer (score 0):

`ui-sref` will be only available on anchor tag. If you use `button`, you have to call to action from controller.

```
<button 
  ng-click="go('challenges.show', { challengeId: challenge.id })">
     Change state
</button>
```

**Controller**

```
$scope.go = $state.go;
```

Comment: Is there a way to achieve this without adding extra elements?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, but neither of these answer the question, i.e. how to change state on button click.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use `a` tag but style it as a button?